# jQuery selector across the whole table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a page which loads with checkboxes checked which should become selected, I achieve this using the below:

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    table.row($row).select();
});
```

This works great, however it is unable to select table rows which are in any other than the first page.

I found on dataTables there is a method to select across the whole table, however I am having difficulty in applying it and hoping someone might show me where I am going wrong:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()

https://jsfiddle.net/26tw0ujh/

There is a page reload button, if you select items on another page then reload, only checked items on the first page become selected.

Comment: FYI, in JS Fiddle,  CSS and JS should be added from the `External Resources` column to the left of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table.$` like with a jQuery selector.

```
table.$('input:checked').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');           
    table.row($row).select();
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/26tw0ujh/2/)**

Comment: Cheers, I only needed to prefix the code in my question with ```.table```
Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/d3tbvzg9/

Comment: Yes, I read the question wrong at the first time. I've updated my answer to your needs. ;) @user3770935